# Cisco 1921 VPN Clients IP address assignment

Tags: cisco, vpn, ip-address

I have Cisco 1921 working as L2TP server without IPsec configured as follows:

```
!
aaa authentication ppp default local
aaa authorization network default local 
!
username User1 password 7 ***
username User2 password 7 ***
username User3 password 7 ***
username User4 password 7 ***
!
vpdn-group L2TP
 accept-dialin
  protocol l2tp
  virtual-template 10
 lcp renegotiation on-mismatch
 no l2tp tunnel authentication
 ip pmtu
 ip mtu adjust
!
interface Virtual-Template10
 ip unnumbered GigabitEthernet0/0.20
 ip nat enable
 peer default ip address pool L2TP-POOL
 ppp encrypt mppe auto
 ppp authentication ms-chap ms-chap-v2
!
ip local pool L2TP-POOL 172.16.28.1 172.16.28.30
!
```

L2TP clients work though unstable 3G connection and often loses connection. After reconnecting they often get assigned with different IP address from pool.

Is it possible to configure server to assign same IP addresses to each username every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to configure server to assign same IP addresses to each username every time?

If you configure the 1921 LNS to request authentication from a RADIUS server, yes, it is possible, since you can use RADIUS to attach a specific address for every user.

I do not know whether it is possible with local user authentication on the Cisco router itself.